# Width not responding on android browser only on samsung galaxy tab 3

Tags: android, html, css, browser

I'm having a very weird issue with a page design, it works well in almost every device and resolution, the only issue is with the android browser on Samsung galaxy tab 3 with 1280x800 res. The width of the box is too wide on the Samsung galaxy tab, any ideas?

I'm using sass/compass but the code is very long to paste it here, same as compiled css.

BASIC HTML

https://jsfiddle.net/nayL9wt9/2/

BASIC SASS:

```
.group-product-info {
          min-height: 0;
          max-height: 100%;
          height: 65% !important;
          width: 40.65% !important; //Original width
          max-width: 40.65% !important;
          overflow: auto;
          -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of how it should look:

[image]

Samsung Galaxy Tab view:

[image]

Comment: Please provide some markup also. Looks like first version is 40% of the image it is overlaying and the second looks like it is 40% of the page width.

Comment: @hungerstar sorry I think I don't understand what do you mean with markups?

Comment: Can you supply your HTML in your question above or create a https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @ui-matt I will resume it and publish here soon, now I understand, but give me a while please

Comment: @RicardoRios markup = HTML.

Comment: Added a small resume of html/css the code is very long to paste all here